# TFS users just allowed to create bugs

Tags: testing, tfs, permissions, azure-devops

We have a VSTO account and we are currently opening a test environment for one of our customer.
We want to provide to this customer a way to declare bugs and see all the bugs that are currently declared.
We just want to allow these permissions but in the VSTS groups, there is no "tester" group.
What is the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

The tier/group/access level I think that will help you is the Stakeholders Access Level. People with the Stakeholders Access Level will be able to create/see work items, etc., but not your source.

Also Stakeholders are free.

To see the difference between Stakeholder and Basic, https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-feature-matrix-vs and http://vsalmdocs.azurewebsites.net/library/vs/alm/work/connect/work-as-a-stakeholder

You add a user as a Stakeholder via the Users tab on the main dashboard.

Go to your VSTS site, https://[yourprojectname].visualstudio.com/
There should be a "Users" tab/link there are the top, right below the Team Services logo, click on it
Under All Users, click on Add, enter their sign-in info and the key, set their Access Level to Stakeholder

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "Tester" group and add the customer via following steps:

1. Open your project from Web Portal.
2. Click "Manage project" button in the up-right corner.
3. Switch to "Security" tab.
4. Click "Create VSTS group" button to create the "Tester" group.
5. Click "Add..." button under "Members" tab of "Tester" group to add your customer.

And then you can configure the permissions for this group base on your requirement.

1. Under "Security" tab, you can set the general permissions.
2. Under "Version Control" tab, you can set the permissions to access your code resource. Click "Add..." button to add the created "Tester" group and set all the permissions to "Deny" for "Tester" group since you just want to give the customer the permissions to check bugs.
3. Under "Work" tab, switch to "Area" panel. Since there isn't any way to specify the permission base on the work item types. The alternative way to do this would be create a child area and place all your bugs under this area. Then you can configure the security setting for parent area and child area so that the "Tester" group can only read and edit the work items under bug area.

By the way, if you only have just one customer need to apply these settings, you can also configure the security for the customer directly by searching the customer name and then setting the permissions without create a group.